# Compound Interest Function in C++

Tags: c++, function

Ok, after working on this for an embarrassing number of hours, I think I came up with something less cringe-worthy to ya'll "real" programmers.
Allow me to submit my humble and probably awful code.
It totally works, but now my issue is that I'm trying to make it go back to an initial question if the response is a negative number.  I got it to say, "Hey! Don't put in a negative number!", but then it goes to the next prompt.  Here's my current output for a negative input:

** Welcome to the Consumer Loan Calculator **
How much would you like to borrow? $-100
Please enter a positive loan amount.
What is your annual percentage rate? %

...And for a positive input:

** Welcome to the Consumer Loan Calculator **
How much would you like to borrow? $100
How much would you like to borrow? $100
How much would you like to borrow? $

I want it to go back to "How much would you like to borrow?" if the user input is negative and only go to the next question if the input is positive.  What am I doing wrong now?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void get_input (double &principal, double &APR, double mon_pay);

int main()
{
    double loan; // principal
    double APR; // APR
    double mon_pay; //monthly payment

    cout << "** Welcome to the Consumer Loan Calculator **"<<endl;
    do {
        cout << "How much would you like to borrow? $";
        cin >>loan;
        if (loan < 0)
        cout <<"Please enter a positive loan amount.";
        }
    while (loan > 0);
    cout << "What is your annual percentage rate? %";
    cin >>APR;
    cout << "What is your monthly payment? $";
    cin >> mon_pay;

    APR = APR/100;
    get_input (loan, APR, mon_pay);

}

void get_input (double &principal, double &APR, double mon_pay)
{
    double total, add=0; // Total payment
    int tpay=1; //Total months of payment

    while (principal > 0)
    {
        add = principal * (APR/100);
        principal = ((principal+add) - mon_pay);
        tpay++;
    }

    total = mon_pay + principal;
    cout << "Your debt will be paid off after "<< tpay << " months, with a final payment of just $" <<setprecision(3)<<total<<endl;
    cout <<"Don't get overwhelmed with debt!"<<std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Consider adding the homework tag.

Comment: I just checked and wasn't able to find a tag for homework.  Thank you for the suggestion.  Do you happen to have any suggestions about my question?

Comment: See my answer for suggestions.

Comment: @erip The homework tag has been gone for quite a while.  If you ask a good question it doesn't matter if it is homework or not.

Comment: @RetiredNinja - I'm doing my best to learn how to ask good questions as well.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

this line is definately wrong:

```
while (int tp=1, double p <= double m, double sub--m)
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Yes.  Totally aware of that.  Maybe I should ask a different question here:
What would be the best way to create this loop? While? Do while? For?
I'm all for figuring things out on my own and I understand the math involved, but I need to be pointed in the right direction with how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, there are a lot of problems with this code. I would recommend for starts to eliminate all global variables. They'll make your code more confusing to debug and it's considered bad practice *generally* to use them.

Furthermore, I would choose more descriptive identifiers for your variables -- it'll make the logic less abstruse. For example, `m` is a poor choice for a variable name. Why not choose `monthly_pay` or something more clear?

Additionally, while loops take arguments that are **boolean**. What you've written doesn't make sense and I'm honestly not sure what the compiler would do if it isn't screaming now. My guess is that it would be in an infinite loop from the `int tp=1` always evaluating to true.

Finally, it's worthwhile to learn to modularize code. Based on your code, I'd venture to say you're a beginner in the realm of code. It's very good practice (and follows in logic nicely) to modularize your code. What logical steps would you follow if you were doing this by hand?

1. Greet user
2. Get input
3. Do some calculations
4. Output to user
5. Say goodbye

If there are more details, expected outputs, etc., I'd recommend adding them to your question or risk being flagged as too broad.

Good luck on your homework.
erip

**EDIT**

Totally forgot about functions.

Functions, like in math, require arguments.

f(x) = x^2 + 2x - 1. The argument to this function is obviously x.

In programming, some functions require arguments as well.

Let's say you're trying to model [this](https://qrc.depaul.edu/StudyGuide2009/Notes/Savings%20Accounts/Compound%20Interest.htm) equation...

You might consider doing something like this:

```
#include <math.h>

double compound_interest(double r, int n, double t, double P)
{
    return P*pow((1+ r/n), n*t);
}
```

So if you want to call this in your main

```
//insert header stuff, function declarations, etc.

int main()
{
   double rate = 0.1, // 10% 
          time = 10.0,    // 10 months
          principle = 125.00, // $125.00 
          accumulated; // This is what we want to know
   int payment_period = 12; // 12 months

   accumulated = compound_interest(rate, payment_period, time, principle);

   cout << "Total accumulated cost is " << accumulated << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Small note, I don't think this will work because I don't remember the type of arguments that `pow` takes, but it can be manipulated.

Comment: Hi there-

@erip I appreciate the fact that you took the time to try to answer my question.  Yes, I am a beginner.  I'm 35, with a career & 2 college degrees.  I'm trying to learn this to further my career.  I realize a lot of people come her to get their homework done for them, but not everyone.  Some of us are legitimately trying to learn this (and, in my case, need extra help to understand!).  None of you came out of the womb coding.  Everyone has to learn.  Down voting posts asking for help is just rude.  Help or don't help.  It wouldn't kill anyone to keep the snark to a minimum, though.

Comment: I'm neither *intentionally* being rude nor did I down vote. I'm not being snarky. I realize you're trying to learn and that's why I answered so comprehensively. If you were offended, I'm sorry. Totally not my goal. Good luck.

Comment: My apologies, @ericp.  That part was not aimed at you.  I truly appreciated your input. I looked up modular coding at your suggestion & it was a big help!  The snark comment was aimed at the other commenters & down voters.  It seems to happen a lot to programming novices & it gets frustrating after a while.  When I was younger & had thinner skin it might have put me off learning to code.  I understand that it's irritating when people try to get their homework done for them, but it's rough on the other aspiring coders who have to subject themselves to unrelenting nerd abuse just to get help.